# Entering an encrytion phrase through a serial port connection

Tags: command-line, server, password, encryption

I am building an Ubuntu 14.04 stand alone server, text install.  I have rerouted the console through serial port /dev/ttyS0.  During boot I am getting the full boot up display through the serial port.  I am using Putty to log directly to the Server serial port through the serial port on my laptop.  I have a Null modem cable.

The Problem:
When the server boots and sends the console display through the serial port and it gets to the encryption password it stops for a password.

1. When try to enter an encryption password when its asks for one on the serial port my typed characters are "not" entered on the putty console.  I press return and nothing happens.
2. If I am plugged into a monitor and keyboard and am monitoring the serial output at the same time, I can enter the password in the console keyboard but not Putty.
3. When I enter the password on the main console the boot up continues normally and at that time I can enter a normal log in password in Putty and log in to the server through Putty.  But never am I able to send characters for the encryption password through the serial port.

How can I send characters through Putty at the time the server asks for the Encrypted Password?

Thanks.